# Are all CSS applied in document.load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create function which will invoke after every part of the document is loaded and applied.

So: are all css applied in `document.load`? Does `document.load` invoke if some resources will have 404 error?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me and if you are trying to apply css after entire document is loaded than it doesn't make sense to me :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: It sounds to me like "will 404 errors keep the `load` event from firing?".

Comment: @Garath : Why dont you create an example page with a 404 resource and see if the document.load event is fired or not?

Comment: @ClydeLobo - in google chrome you can access developer tools and view the resource tab to see if something didnt load.

Comment: @Garath - What programming language do you use. I dont understand, are you spesifying the css to be outputed by Javascript, or in HTML or is it created dynamicly using php

Comment: @ClydeLobo Are you sure that my test will be reliable in all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The load event will fire after the entire, initial document (including dependancies), as described by the HTML (and CSS) source, has loaded.

Content added to the DOM with JavaScript may not finish loading until after the load event had fired.

Comment: what will happened in some of the resources will not load (404 for example)? I can create test bu check it in all browsers could be difficult

Comment: 404s won't effect it.